# Cómo Podria mostrar GIT BASH con clic derecho en cualquier directorio de windows

Tags: web, git, aplicación-web, git-bash

instale git portable , no la setup ;

al momento de querer abrir una carpeta en gitbash no me figura, me podrian indicar cual seria el problema y alguna solucion.
Muchas Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Échale un ojo a esto a ver si funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386657/how-to-add-a-open-git-bash-here-context-menu-to-the-windows-explorer Para mi que no toco güindous ni con un palo de 3 metros, esto se ve un poco espeluznante.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte